# Framework/architecture for generating simple HTML controls

Tags: html, jsp, architecture, frameworks

I'm just wondering/deeply thinking about whether any framework/architecture/library exist that would help in automatically generating simple HTML controls along with its label.

For example, I'm just simply envisioning as described below.  If I define controls and its characteristics somewhere (may be in Database, in XML form, etc.), then the framework should able to generate the controls.  In this case, am not much worried about the validation of each fields.

```
LABEL        |    CONTROL
Name         |    Textbox
Age          |    Textbox
Sex          |    Radio button
State        |    Drop-down
Description  |    Textarea
```

In case of drop-down list, is it possible to map/relate to a list/lookup, so that drop-down list values are populated automatically?

Any links/resources/blogs/suggestions are also appreciated.

**NOTE:** Our tools of trade are: Java, JDK1.6, JSP, Apache Tomcat v6.0.10, PostgreSQL v8.2.3

**UPDATE:** Please feel free to retag my question, if it needs to represent the actual question topic.

Answer (score 0):

you can use XSLT transformation to achieve this..
[here is a link](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) which can help you on XSLT

for input fields you can use something like ..

```
<input id="Name" type="text" value="{value}"/>
```

XSLT can be used as a template against which a html can be generated.

Comment: Your comment seems to be broader in nature.  Can you point/link me to some specific use case/example?

Comment: XSLT is a technique where you transform XML formatted data to another format (say html or pdf, csv etc.,), 

i can provide you with a couple of links to start you off with XSLT.. its fairly easy. here is a [link from Oracle site] [1] and [another one][2] from O'Reilly publication's book

[1]:http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPXSLT6.html
[2]:http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kit/2004k/ctl257/JavaXSLT/Ch05.html

Comment: I read about those links.  But my question is *subtle different*, am expecting HTML control itself to be generated automatically.  I also understand your view that HTML can be generated out of XSL templates. Any different ideas/approach?

Comment: HTML controls are generated based on the HTML provided.. here the controls are generated in a web browser... the idea here is to generate the appropriate HTML for a control so that the control is rendered.

Comment: If you could share some simple working example code on this, it'll be more helpful.